# Display contact database by all categories it is marked, then alphabetical order

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while-loop

I'm trying to build a Vendor Contact Database with categories. Various vendors are marked under more than one category. I have structured my table as the following:

```
Name_Vendor | Category_1 | Category_2 | Category_3 |

John Smith  | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Plumber Jim | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

**My Current Code**

```
$category_Title_1 = "Appliance Repair";
$category_1 = "Category_1";
$category_Title_2 = "Handyman";
$category_2 = "Category_2";
$category_Title_3 = "Plumber";
$category_3 = "Category_3";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `vendors` WHERE ".$category_1 ."='1'ORDER BY Name_Vendor ASC");
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
if ($row_cnt == 0 ){echo "<div>";}
else
{ echo "<div>".$category_Title_1."</div>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { echo $row['Name_Vendor'];
    echo "</div>";}
    
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `vendors` WHERE ".$category_2 ."='1'ORDER BY Name_Vendor ASC");
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
if ($row_cnt == 0 ){echo "<div>";}
else
{ echo "<div>".$category_Title_2."</div>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { echo $row['Name_Vendor'];
    echo "</div>";}

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `vendors` WHERE ".$category_3 ."='1'ORDER BY Name_Vendor ASC");
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
if ($row_cnt == 0 ){echo "<div>";}
else
{ echo "<div>".$category_Title_3."</div>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    { echo $row['Name_Vendor'];
    echo "</div>";}
```

This is just a basic idea. My contact database has more fields including phone number, email, etc.

Seeing how our category numbers have grown to a large amount, I'm looking for a way to not have to copy the same code multiple times within the same page in order to display all the categories.

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is a Loop in conjunction with an Array or two.

Comment: place the categories in an array, and loop through those categories using a foreach loop that will resolve your redundant coding issue above. you can store all your results in a key,value pair array, where the key is the category & value would be your results from the executed query

Comment: Normalize your data and your code will be simpler.

Comment: @mcv Would you be able to give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$keyValuePairArray = {
   'key1' => 'value1',
   'key2' => 'value2',
   ...
};

foreach($keyValuePairArray as $key=>$value){
   //do whatever it is that you're doing 
   //repetitively in your code above
   //if you don't understand this try using var_dump on your array
   //and echo out the $key and $value so that you might better understand
   //or research about all the items I have mentioned previously
}
```

- [PHP Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [PHP ForEach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)